# Problem with WPF graph control

Tags: wpf, gdi

I've developed a graph control in GDI+ and used a timer in it.. now i'm converting it to 
WPF. but when i went on and search for a timer there is no timers in WPF... how can i resolve this problem?any alternative to use?

regards,
rangana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Threading.Timer` without any problems I suppose.

Here is an example of a timer which executes every 1 sec:

```
using System.Threading;

...

TimerCallback timerCallBack = OnTimerCallback;
Timer timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, 0, 1000);

...

private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to update any UI related elements from the timer, you will have to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` because the timer runs in it's own thread and the UI is owned by the main thread which starts the timer. Here is an example:

```
private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart) (() => Background = Brushes.Black));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The timer you are looking for is DispatcherTimer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

But, if you plan to use a timer to drive animations, there are better ways to do that in WPF (just Google WPF animation).